# Kibana: No Living connections

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have ES 1.5.2 cluster with Kibana 4.0.1. This consists of 4 data/master nodes along with 4 client nodes. 
When I'm trying to load kibana sometimes it takes longer time to load or sometimes I need to restart the ES client node which kibana is pointed to. 
When the issue is there,

I get below console error in Kibana page

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE - http://xx.xx.xx.xx /elasticsearch/_nodes
```

and below error in ES log

```
[2016-01-15 07:01:52,629][DEBUG][http.netty] [xxxxxx] Caught exception while handling client http traffic, closing connection [id: 0x8301fd2b, /xx.xx.xx.xx:54237 :> /xx.xx.xx.xx:9200]
```

*All the masters has below config*

```
"index" : {
          "number_of_shards" : "3"
        },
        "bootstrap" : {
          "mlockall" : "true"
        },
        "threadpool" : {
          "search" : {
            "queue_size" : "2000",
            "size" : "20"
          }
"indices" : {
          "fielddata" : {
            "cache" : {
              "size" : "50%"
            }
          }
        },
        "discovery" : {
          "zen" : {
            "master_election" : {
              "filter_client" : "true"
            },
            "ping" : {
              "multicast" : {
                "enabled" : "false"
              },
              "timeout" : "6s",
              "unicast" : {
                "hosts" : [ "xxxx", "xxx", "xxxx" ]
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "name" : "xxxxx",
        "http" : {
          "enabled" : "true"
        },
        "action" : {
          "disable_delete_all_indices" : "true"
        },
        "client" : {
          "type" : "node"
        },
        "config" : "/xxxxx/elasticsearch-1.5.2/config/elasticsearch.yml"
      },
      "os" : {
        "refresh_interval_in_millis" : 1000,
        "available_processors" : 4,
        "cpu" : {
          "vendor" : "Intel",
          "model" : "Xeon",
          "mhz" : 2400,
          "total_cores" : 4,
          "total_sockets" : 2,
          "cores_per_socket" : 2,
          "cache_size_in_bytes" : 30720
        },
        "mem" : {
          "total_in_bytes" : 16820760576
        },
        "swap" : {
          "total_in_bytes" : 2145382400
        }
      },
      "process" : {
        "refresh_interval_in_millis" : 1000,
        "id" : 48090,
        "max_file_descriptors" : 65535,
        "mlockall" : true
      },
      "jvm" : {
        "pid" : 48090,
        "version" : "1.8.0_45",
        "vm_name" : "Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM",
        "vm_version" : "25.45-b02",
        "vm_vendor" : "Oracle Corporation",
        "start_time_in_millis" : 1452791955862,
        "mem" : {
          "heap_init_in_bytes" : 8589934592,
          "heap_max_in_bytes" : 8555069440,
          "non_heap_init_in_bytes" : 2555904,
          "non_heap_max_in_bytes" : 0,
          "direct_max_in_bytes" : 8555069440
        },
        "gc_collectors" : [ "ParNew", "ConcurrentMarkSweep" ],
        "memory_pools" : [ "Code Cache", "Metaspace", "Compressed Class Space", "Par Eden Space", "Par Survivor Space", "CMS Old Gen" ]
      },
      "thread_pool" : {
        "percolate" : {
          "type" : "fixed",
          "min" : 4,
          "max" : 4,
          "queue_size" : "1k"
        },
        "listener" : {
          "type" : "fixed",
          "min" : 2,
          "max" : 2,
          "queue_size" : -1
        },
        "index" : {
          "type" : "fixed",
          "min" : 4,
          "max" : 4,
          "queue_size" : "200"
        },
        "refresh" : {
          "type" : "scaling",
          "min" : 1,
          "max" : 2,
          "keep_alive" : "5m",
          "queue_size" : -1
        },
        "suggest" : {
          "type" : "fixed",
          "min" : 4,
          "max" : 4,
          "queue_size" : "1k"
        },
        "generic" : {
          "type" : "cached",
          "keep_alive" : "30s",
          "queue_size" : -1
        },
        "warmer" : {
          "type" : "scaling",
          "min" : 1,
          "max" : 2,
          "keep_alive" : "5m",
          "queue_size" : -1
        },
        "search" : {
          "type" : "fixed",
          "min" : 20,
          "max" : 20,
          "queue_size" : "2k"
        },
        "flush" : {
          "type" : "scaling",
          "min" : 1,
          "max" : 2,
          "keep_alive" : "5m",
          "queue_size" : -1
        },
        "optimize" : {
          "type" : "fixed",
          "min" : 1,
          "max" : 1,
          "queue_size" : -1
        },
        "management" : {
          "type" : "scaling",
          "min" : 1,
          "max" : 5,
          "keep_alive" : "5m",
          "queue_size" : -1
        },
        "get" : {
          "type" : "fixed",
          "min" : 4,
          "max" : 4,
          "queue_size" : "1k"
        },
        "merge" : {
          "type" : "scaling",
          "min" : 1,
          "max" : 2,
          "keep_alive" : "5m",
          "queue_size" : -1
        },
        "bulk" : {
          "type" : "fixed",
          "min" : 4,
          "max" : 4,
          "queue_size" : "50"
        },
        "snapshot" : {
          "type" : "scaling",
          "min" : 1,
          "max" : 2,
          "keep_alive" : "5m",
          "queue_size" : -1
        }
      },
      "network" : {
        "refresh_interval_in_millis" : 5000,
        "primary_interface" : {
          "address" : "xxxxxx",
          "name" : "eth0",
          "mac_address" : "xxxxxxx"
        }
      },
      "transport" : {
        "bound_address" : "inet[/xxxxx:9300]",
        "publish_address" : "inet[/1xxxx:9300]",
        "profiles" : { }
      },
      "http" : {
        "bound_address" : "inet[/1xxxxx:9200]",
        "publish_address" : "inet[/xxxxx:9200]",
        "max_content_length_in_bytes" : 104857600
      },
```

*All the clients has below config*

```
"index" : {
          "number_of_shards" : "3"
        },
        "bootstrap" : {
          "mlockall" : "true"
        },
        "threadpool" : {
          "search" : {
            "queue_size" : "2000",
            "size" : "20"
          }
"indices" : {
          "fielddata" : {
            "cache" : {
              "size" : "50%"
            }
          }
        },
        "discovery" : {
          "zen" : {
            "master_election" : {
              "filter_client" : "true"
            },
            "ping" : {
              "multicast" : {
                "enabled" : "false"
              },
              "timeout" : "6s",
              "unicast" : {
                "hosts" : [ "xx.xx.xx.xx", "xx.xx.xx.xx", "xx.xx.xx.xx", "xx.xx.xx.xx" ]
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "name" : "xxxxxx",
        "action" : {
          "disable_delete_all_indices" : "true"
        },
        "client" : {
          "type" : "node"
        },
        "config" : "/xxxx/elasticsearch-1.5.2/config/elasticsearch.yml"
      },
      "os" : {
        "refresh_interval_in_millis" : 1000,
        "available_processors" : 2,
        "cpu" : {
          "vendor" : "Intel",
          "model" : "Xeon",
          "mhz" : 2400,
          "total_cores" : 2,
          "total_sockets" : 1,
          "cores_per_socket" : 2,
          "cache_size_in_bytes" : 30720
        },
        "mem" : {
          "total_in_bytes" : 8365080576
        },
        "swap" : {
          "total_in_bytes" : 2145382400
        }
      },
      "process" : {
        "refresh_interval_in_millis" : 1000,
        "id" : 34778,
        "max_file_descriptors" : 65535,
        "mlockall" : true
      },
      "jvm" : {
        "pid" : 34778,
        "version" : "1.8.0_45",
        "vm_name" : "Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM",
        "vm_version" : "25.45-b02",
        "vm_vendor" : "Oracle Corporation",
        "start_time_in_millis" : 1452792092500,
        "mem" : {
          "heap_init_in_bytes" : 4294967296,
          "heap_max_in_bytes" : 4277534720,
          "non_heap_init_in_bytes" : 2555904,
          "non_heap_max_in_bytes" : 0,
          "direct_max_in_bytes" : 4277534720
        },
        "gc_collectors" : [ "ParNew", "ConcurrentMarkSweep" ],
        "memory_pools" : [ "Code Cache", "Metaspace", "Compressed Class Space", "Par Eden Space", "Par Survivor Space", "CMS Old Gen" ]
      },
      "thread_pool" : {
        "percolate" : {
          "type" : "fixed",
          "min" : 2,
          "max" : 2,
          "queue_size" : "1k"
        },
        "listener" : {
          "type" : "fixed",
          "min" : 1,
          "max" : 1,
          "queue_size" : -1
        },
        "index" : {
          "type" : "fixed",
          "min" : 2,
          "max" : 2,
          "queue_size" : "200"
        },
        "refresh" : {
          "type" : "scaling",
          "min" : 1,
          "max" : 1,
          "keep_alive" : "5m",
          "queue_size" : -1
        },
        "suggest" : {
          "type" : "fixed",
          "min" : 2,
          "max" : 2,
          "queue_size" : "1k"
        },
        "generic" : {
          "type" : "cached",
          "keep_alive" : "30s",
          "queue_size" : -1
        },
        "warmer" : {
          "type" : "scaling",
          "min" : 1,
          "max" : 1,
          "keep_alive" : "5m",
          "queue_size" : -1
        },
        "search" : {
          "type" : "fixed",
          "min" : 20,
          "max" : 20,
          "queue_size" : "2k"
        },
        "flush" : {
          "type" : "scaling",
          "min" : 1,
          "max" : 1,
          "keep_alive" : "5m",
          "queue_size" : -1
        },
        "optimize" : {
          "type" : "fixed",
          "min" : 1,
          "max" : 1,
          "queue_size" : -1
        },
        "management" : {
          "type" : "scaling",
          "min" : 1,
          "max" : 5,
          "keep_alive" : "5m",
          "queue_size" : -1
        },
        "get" : {
          "type" : "fixed",
          "min" : 2,
          "max" : 2,
          "queue_size" : "1k"
        },
        "merge" : {
          "type" : "scaling",
          "min" : 1,
          "max" : 1,
          "keep_alive" : "5m",
          "queue_size" : -1
        },
        "bulk" : {
          "type" : "fixed",
          "min" : 2,
          "max" : 2,
          "queue_size" : "50"
        },
        "snapshot" : {
          "type" : "scaling",
          "min" : 1,
          "max" : 1,
          "keep_alive" : "5m",
          "queue_size" : -1
        }
      },
      "network" : {
        "refresh_interval_in_millis" : 5000,
        "primary_interface" : {
          "address" : "xx.xx.xx.xx",
          "name" : "eth0",
          "mac_address" : "xx.xx.xx.xx"
        }
      },
      "transport" : {
        "bound_address" : "inet[/xx.xx.xx.xx:9300]",
        "publish_address" : "inet[/xx.xx.xx.xx:9300]",
        "profiles" : { }
      },
      "http" : {
        "bound_address" : "inet[/xx.xx.xx.xx:9200]",
        "publish_address" : "inet[/xx.xx.xx.xx:9200]",
        "max_content_length_in_bytes" : 104857600
      },
      "plugins" : [ ]
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you made a typo or what but in the log I see

```
http://xx.xx.xx.xx /elasticsearch/_nodes
```

There's a space generally where a port should be unless you map 80->9200

```
http://xx.xx.xx.xx:9200/elasticsearch/_nodes
```

or if you map 80->92000

```
http://xx.xx.xx.xx/elasticsearch/_nodes
```

Comment: Hi Mike, 
xx.xx.xx.xx is my kibana server IP. if I query "http://xx.xx.xx.xx/elasticsearch/_nodes " will return node information when aforesaid issue not there.

Comment: i know that.. I'm just wondering the space in your question between the xxx and /elasticsearch in the uri error log

Answer (score 1):

Finally found the issue. I had two client nodes in different network. 
Adjusting tcp keepalive parameters in ubuntu servers fixed the issue.

```
tcp_keepalive_time 
tcp_keepalive_intvl 
tcp_keepalive_probes
```